# Check if any array is equalvalent in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, but how can I check if any arrays (A, B, C, D,...) are equal to one another.

E.g.

A = [1, 3, 5]

B = [2, 6, 8]

C = [1, 2, 6]

D = [2, 6, 8]

I want to would like to create a script that informs me if any of the arrays are equivalent.  This should return a 1 (for example) because B and D are equivalent.

Unfortunately, isequal tests if all arrays are equal (so this would return a 0 for my hypothetical data set).  So far the only thing I can think of is doing isequal(A,B) | isequal(A,C) | isequal (A,D) | ... | isequal (C,D), but I am hoping to do this with 100+ arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Are all the arrays the same size? And how do you have those arrays defined? It's not a good idea to use separate variables. You should use a matrix (i.e. `[A;B;C;D]`) or a cell array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a 0/1 result:

First define a matrix with all your vectors (assumed all of the same length, as in your example):

```
M = [A;B;C;D];
```

Then use

```
result = size(unique(M,'rows'),1)<size(M,1);
```

or

```
result = any(all(~diff(sortrows(M)).'));
```

or

```
result = nnz(all(bsxfun(@eq, M.', permute(M.', [1 3 2]))))>size(M,1);
```

or

```
result = any(pdist(M,'hamming')==0);
```

or ... :-)